# Wait until a Promise is resolved to pass its result to a React return statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await

I have this object component here that I'm fetching from it data from a local server, I need to wait until the data is downloaded and then pass the information to the return statement of the component. I tried many things but it doesn't seem to work. This is my last try :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReviewItem from './review_item.js'

const ReviewList = async (props) => {

  const form = {
       elementPlayground:"2019A.Kagan",
       elementId:props.element_id,
       type:"ShowReviews",
       attributes: { page:0, size:5 }
  }

  const url = `http://localhost:8083/playground/activities/2019A.Kagan/${props.playground}`

  const getItems = () => {
    return fetch(url, {
                method: "POST",
                mode: "cors",
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(form),
              })
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(json => ((json['attributes'])['reviews']).map(review => <ReviewItem key={json['id']} review={review} />));
  }

    const items = await getItems();
    console.log(items);
    return (
      <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
      {items}
      </ul>
    )
}

export default ReviewList;
```

The item I want to return is "items"
I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: You have no `responseJson` variable. `key={responseJson['id']}` will fail. (also, regarding your `json` variable, you have an *object there*, not a JSON. something in JSON format will be a *string*)

Comment: since `const ReviewList` is `async (props) => {` ... it can only ever return a Promise

Comment: thanks, I just noticed that. It happened from all my tries to figure this out. Anyway, that wasn't the problem, It worked as a class component with the same form and syntax, but I need it to be an object component

Comment: I think you're confused about how async programming works. You need to handle a render before data is returned, and you need to handle a render after it's returned. *How* you manage that is up to you, e.g., you could decide not to render anything until there's data, or you could render a spinner, etc. There are *tons* of examples of how to do this.

Comment: @NathanielFlick It doesn't handle the underlying issue the OP is having; `fetch` is perfectly acceptable. The OP is unsure how to handle async responses w.r.t. rendering.

Comment: Lots of related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breactjs%5D+ajax+request

Answer (score 0):

Still typically new to this, but if I am waiting for a response to display data or prevent further children from loading, I usually set `state` to `isLoading: true` and then when the fetch completes successfully I set `isLoading: false`

Something like this if it helps.

```
return (
  <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
  {!this.state.isLoading && {items}}
  </ul>
)
```